# Не показываеются популярные виджеты на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Использую Open Server.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при поиске определенного плагина - все нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это может быть? и не может ли эта ошибка отразиться на работоспособности сайта?

Answer (score 1):

> и не может ли эта ошибка отразиться на работоспособности сайта?

Это всё на реальном хостинге надо смотреть.